Get currently played media cover with Javascript/electronjs
for a project I'm doing right now I wanted to know something about media in windows. Some apps are able to fetch the cover of the media you are currently platying on your computer (from whatever plateform) and I wanted to know how can this be acheived using javascript and electronjs. If someone can give me a hint or a full answer It would be insane.
I'm putting below a picture of what I'm talking about.

